# Be notified if a question that you have answered for was deleted

Tags: feature-request

I just lost 95 points on SO :-( after a question I answered was deleted. I got no notification of it being deleted. The change in reputation told me the story.

Feature Request: Can this notification message be added?

Comment: downvoter care to comment/

Comment: I am sure there is dupe of this question

Comment: which question?

Comment: What would the point be for such a message? Also, [votes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: FYI please see [meta-faq#vote-differences]. Note that I haven't voted thus don't blame me.

Comment: atleast let you know which question was deleted. It might be important to know the reason for change in the reputation. I had to go hunting for which question got deleted and figured out it was a `perl` tagged question that got -12 votes

Comment: But why would it matter? You can already access a reputation report at `*site*/reputation`; when the question is deleted, it means it _should_ be hidden in general. It just seems pointless to know _which_ question was deleted.

Comment: I don't see the reason for it being hidden.

Comment: Because the question was _deleted_. Clearly, it wasn't too important.

Comment: See also [*Reputation and Historical Archives*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

Comment: Also, you aren't that new. You shouldn't really answer obvious help-vampire/horrible questions that are bound to be closed and deleted, instead, you should comment on them and help either prevent the closing (by editing), or close yourself. If you still want to help the OP, be my guest.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no reputation from your answer, or your answer is *community wiki*, my understanding is that you are never informed of the deletion on your reputation page. Furthermore, *if your answer has been around long enough that you don't lose the reputation* when the question is deleted, you're not notified on the reputation page.

So, if the reason people disagree with this feature request is the belief that one is always notified in one's reputation page, that is an unfounded objection.

Well, sort of unfounded. The question does emphasize knowing the reason one has lost reputation. But I am concerned specifically about **situations were no reputation was lost.** I'm much more interested in understanding why any content I've posted has been deleted, then understanding why I lost a little reputation. And I doubt I'm alone in this.

The desire to know when one's own content is deleted (in this case, at no fault of one's own, but because the question it was posted on was deleted) is reasonable. And I think it's a desire most users have. Most users probably do want to know when questions they've answered are deleted. I know I would like this.

Therefore, some additional notification feature is reasonable here.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of notification are you looking for?  You are more or less notified by your reputation if you have upvotes (or downvotes) on answer for the question that gets removed.  And the reputation tab in your profile will show you not only that a post was removed, but should also show you the title.  Since the post is deleted, you will not get a link to it however, but you can see it was there (if you are a 10K user and have the privilege to see deleted posts, you might get a link, I cannot confirm that myself).

[image]

[image]

In order to see this information, you need to make sure the "Show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom is checked.

[image]

This should really be all notification you need.